# f2py: character array behavior depends on the order of loading modules

Tags: python, fortran, gfortran, openmpi, f2py

I am trying to pass an array of characters from python to a fortran subroutine compiled using f2py with mpif90. But the behavior of the character array passed to the fortran subroutine changes when the loading of module in python code is changed.

#### How to reproduce

Fortran source (`test.F90`):

```
subroutine test(n,m,c)
  implicit none
  integer,intent(in):: n,m
  character,intent(in):: c(n,m)
!f2py intent(in),depend(c):: n=shape(c,0),m=shape(c,1)
  print *,'n,m = ',n,m
  print *,'size(c) = ',size(c)
  print *,c(1,:)
  print *,c(2,:)
  return
end subroutine test
```

Compile it using f2py with mpif90 as,

```
f2py --f90exec=mpif90 -m test -c test.F90
```

This successfully creates `test.cpython-38-darwin.so` file.

Python script (`test01.py`):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import test
    import numpy as np

    c = np.empty((2,3),dtype='c')
    c[0] = '123'
    c[1] = 'abc'
    test.test(c)
```

This python script returns what I expect.

```
$ python test01.py
 n,m =    2      3
 size(c) =    6
 123
 abc
```

But when I change the order of loading modules in the above python script (loading `numpy` before `test`), I get the following error.

```
$ python test01.py
 n,m =      2      3
 size(c) =       1
At line 10 of file test01.F90 (unit = 6, file = 'stdout')
Internal Error: list_formatted_write(): Bad type
```

The size of a character array `c` passed to the fortran is wrong even if the hidden arguments `n` and `m` detected from passed character array `c` are correct.

This error does not happen when I used gfortran instead of mpif90, even if mpif90 wraps gfortran.

Any suggestion/advice is appreciated.

OS and software versions:

- macOS 11.2.2 (MacBook Pro 13-inch 2020)
- Python 3.8.6
- numpy 1.20.1
- f2py version 2
- gfortran (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0_4) 10.2.0
- mpif90 version is same as gfortran (brew info open-mpi : stable 4.1.0)

Comment: Welcome, I suggest to take the [tour].

Comment: Just for confirmation, does it make any difference if the name "test" is changed to "mytest" etc?

Comment: Yes, I tried with different names for both module and function, but this occurs.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Setup: linux, Python 3.9.1, numpy 1.20.0, f2py version 2, gfortran 10.2.0

Comment: Thanks @jack, I also confirmed that this does not occur with python 3.9.2+ even on mac.